# How to create a Puppet fact with ALL IP addresses of the Puppet master

Tags: puppet

I need a comma separated list of ALL IP addresses of a Puppet master so I can set it in the config files on the system of Puppet nodes/agents.

I can get the primary IP with $serverip, but I need all interface addresses.

Is there a way to establish a Puppet fact with this list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you want the puppet masters IPs available as a fact on all the other nodes ?

Look [here](https://github.com/fghaas/puppet-exportfact).

Somewhere in the puppet masters manifest you would need to create a comma separated list of all the puppet masters IPs, then export the fact.

Then on all the other nodes manifests, you would need to import the fact.

Then when you run facter -p on any node, you'll get the puppet masters list of IPs

Comment: Another method without PuppetDB might be http://docs.puppetlabs.com/guides/custom_functions.html

Answer (score 0):

All the interfaces are listed as comma separated values and can be called in manifests like this :

```
$interfaces
```

You can check the variables available through facter using this command :

```
facter --puppet 
facter --puppet | grep interfaces  # will give you the following
interfaces => eth0,eth1,lo,sit0,virbr0
```

ipaddress for all the interfaces are available by :

```
facter --puppet | grep ^ipaddress   # will return these

ipaddress => 1xx.xx.xxx.xxx
ipaddress_eth0 => 1xx.xx.xxx.xxx
ipaddress_lo => 127.0.0.1
ipaddress_virbr0 => 1xx.1xx.1xx.x
```

You can then put them in an array :

```
$allip = unique(flatten([ $ipaddress, $ipaddress_eth0, $ipaddress_lo, $ipaddress_vibr0 ]))
```